# How do I create a multiple tab Excel workbook on a client machine?

Tags: excel

I have a tabbed series of grids on a data preview page.  I now need to import the data from each grid into its own sheet in an Excel workbook.

How could I do this?

BTW, this is on a Mac or a PC.

Comment: Please mention the platform on which you have to generate. Thanks.

Comment: How is this related to web-development? is the website running on a Max or a PC? If the client is running a Mac or a PC then both answers below are still valid.

Comment: What do you mean, "How is this related to web development?" ?  It's a singularly web problem of how to transfer data from the web server to the client in a format that results in a multi-sheet Excel document, without depending on Excel on the web server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this in two ways in the past:

1. Using Excel automation, and using the Excel API on a server to create multiple sheets.
   (Not recommended, but it does work.)
2. Create the XML you would see when you save the equivalent spreadsheet in Excel and upload it as per Samiksha's suggestion.

   Normally I create a template in Excel, save as XML, then I alter the contents of it depending on the data I want to display.

Answer (score 1):

This is for .net C#

```
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition:", "attachment;filename=filename.xls");
Response.Charset = "";
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
this.EnableViewState = false;
System.IO.StringWriter oStringWriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter oHtmlTextWriter = new  System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(oStringWriter);
this.ClearControls(Grid);
Grid.RenderControl(oHtmlTextWriter);
```

If you want to create multiple sheets in single work book then you will have to use a dll.

Comment: I don't want to send the file to the user, I want to create on the client machine.